# What insulation should I be using in south texas for an attached garage

Tags: insulation, garage, texas

Specifically I’m in the Houston area and I see a lot saying to put the vapor barrier on the outside if you’re going to put one. I got Kraft paper backed fiberglass insulation and while watching a video on YouTube someone mentioned the paper is the vapor barrier. Should I put the paper facing the outside or should I be using different insulation? What risks do I incur by putting it in the “standard” way with the paper facing inward?

Comment: Unless working from the outside in, I would use the poly/plastic 4 or 6mil vapour barrier on the outside wall.  Use the kraft paper the usual way facing in, but once in place, slice the paper a few times in the centre.